# mongoose: how to loop through an array containing object references (_id)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I have a meanjs project and I am getting some input from user on server and the request body has the following structure:

```
{
   transaction: { 
       heading: '',
       items: [Object]    
   },
   something: {},
   somethingAgain: {}
}
```

The structure of the items array is as follows -

```
[ { ref: '5607c6536e67edb44a6a8186',
    name: '',
    quantity: 0,
    discount: 0,
    cost: 180 } ]
```

where the `ref` is the `_id` value of the item in my Item model.
So, basically what I want to do is loop through the array of items and populate the properties of each ref and compute the `cost` property accordingly for each item.
I cannot use a simple for loop as it would execute itself before even the first async call to mongodb to find the item is completed. 
So, how to approach this ? Please suggest.

So, adding more information to the question - 
My server side controller code receiving the request is as follows -

```
exports.create = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.transaction.items);
    Sale.create(req.body, function (err, sale) {
        if (err) {
            return handleError(res, err);
        }
        return res.json(201, sale);
    });
};
```

and the log output of the items is as I have shown above. so what I have to do here is iterate over the items array and find the items with `ref` matching to that of the Items collections.

Comment: Have you looked at Mongoose's population feature? http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Can you provide some more information, maybe a code sample, for what exactly you are doing on the server?

Comment: okay, gimme a sec. I will edit the post. @JohnnyHK I thought of populating  but then I only need a restricted set of records from the whole Items collection. So, If I were to populate I would find all the records and then populate them or is there any way by which I could  pass in a query in the mongoose find method to select only those records whose "_id" value I have stored in the 'ref' property in the items array

Comment: I have edited the post. @abiwer

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why can you not just iterate over the items before making the mongo call?

Comment: No I can't simply iterate, i need to make asynchronous calls to mongodb and then finalize the response once all calls to Mongodb are finished

Comment: I think I got it. So you need to make a few calls, wait for them to finish, then make one more to wrap everything up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90910/discussion-between-abiwer-and-deadman).

Comment: Use populate as suggested by @JohnnyHK

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, I would suggest using [Kris Kowal's q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) for this. Its a small promise library you can use with node. Angular's $q is based on it. Here is an example:

```
function(req, res){

    var calls = [];

    calls.push(Collection1.save());

    calls.push(Collection2.save());

    calls.push(Collection3.save());

    q.all(calls).then(function(call1res, call2res, call3res){
        res.json({whaterver:''});
    });
}
```